# How to detect the front-end actions at the back-end?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, gwt

I'm new to JavaScript environment and it's the one running on the system i'm newly at. 
We're using GWT for JavaScript.

What is the best way to detect the connections between the back-end processes 
and front-end actions? Eg. which back-end method is invoked when "that" button is pressed, tab is clicked, 
window is opened, ... .

The only way I can think of is using the debugger and Eclipse search/call hierarchies facilities: keep putting breakpoints 
in places where I anticipate will run-- until i hit the spot.

Is/n't there a more efficient way of doing this?

How do other developers do?

I'm a back-end developer. 
In a previous system, I put a port monitor-- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/), 
saw the contents of the request the FE is sending and went from there.

I'm aware that this is a naive Q-- please bear with me.

TIA.

//======================

EDIT:

the best would be a 
debugger-like tool showing the stack-trace, or even the 
execution path in any way, telling the back-end methods that are running and/or spawning the threads. 
is there such a tool?

Answer (score 5):

The following takes for granted that you are using a decent IDE and that you have imported the GWT project into such IDE. There's some help at the end if this is not your case.

#### If you know which Java class contains the front-end logic, and the element you're interested in

Find the object representing the element (a `Button`, a `ListBox`, whatever) and look at the event handlers attached to it.
Something like this:

```
//...
@UiField
ListBox myDropDownList;
//...
    myDropDownList.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            SomeService.someRPCmethod(... params, callback, ...);
        }
    });
```

The `SomeService.someRPCmethod` method implementation should contain all the backend calls.

#### If you know the Java class, but not which one of all the buttons is the one you're looking for

Most GWT apps make use of `*.ui.xml` files which are like a skeleton for the actual web page. This XML files reference the actual Java objects used in the Java class, and are usually named like the class they represent.
Locate the `ui.xml` file and look for something like this:

```
...
<g:ListBox ui:field="myDropDownList" styleName="cssClassName"/>
...
```

This should appear in your webpage like this:

```
<select class="cssClassName" ...>
    <option ...>
```

The position inside the XML file, and the CSS class name, should help you pinpoint the element you're looking for. Once you find it, the `ui:field` attribute points to the Java object (try ctrl+clicking it in your IDE).
Now you just have to look at the handlers as explained before.

#### If you don't know the Java class which contains the front-end logic

To find the Java class for a given webpage, you can resort to the good ol' string search.
Locate a not-so-common string literal used in the web page. Not something like "Add" but more like "User registration".
Use your IDE to search the project's code base for that string. It should appear inside a `.properties` file, or a class with constants and literals, or maybe even hardcoded inside the front-end Java class.
Now just use your IDE to follow the references. It might be something like `.properties` file -> `Constants` interface -> `.ui.xml` file -> front-end Java class, or literals Java class -> front-end Java class.

#### If you don't have access to the front-end source code

You can try to use your Developer Tools / Fiddler to look for REST calls, which is how GWT implements RPC.
So the call to `SomeService.someRPCmethod` above *might* appear in Fiddler as a `http:://yourwebpage/somepath/SomeService` call with a bunch of GET/POST parameters, one of which should be `someRPCmethod` (the method's name). But this is not always the case.

If you're running GWT 2.6+ in SuperDev mode with Sources enabled, you can also try to debug the Javascript in the front-end until you reach the RPC calls. See [abhinav3414's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049335/6404321).

#### Last (or maybe first!) resource

Ask the front-end developers, they put the calls in there and can get you on track in minutes ;)

Comment: If I have access to the front-end source code, a string search is what I usually do when inspecting the front-end of a technology I don't know. No matter if it's GWT, or JSP, or Angular, or Python... the strings that I see in the front-end, have to be mapped somewhere in the source code and I can use them to trace the main class / page / component / module.

Comment: If I don't have access to the front-end code and there are no HTTP requests to help me, then I use the back-end logs to see what's going on. Set the log level to debug, do a couple of actions in the front-end, and inspect the logs to see what turns up. I probably won't see `"someRPCmethod"` clearly in the logs, but maybe something like `"[DEBUG] User registered successfully"` which I can then use to do a string search in my back-end code.

Comment: If I don't have access to the front-end code, and I can't see the HTTP requests, and I don't have access to the back-end logs... Well, maybe I'm not the right person for the task! Give me access, give me help, or give the task to someone else ;)

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I updated my answer with some notes about GWT's SuperDev mode. I'm afraid your first comment is indeed very generic, but I hope my comments helped you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, so I installed an extension in my chrome.Below is the name of the extension. You can try once.

**Visual Event 2.1**

```
Know what event is bound on each dom element
```

**There is one more approach**, You can debug your code from front end. You can inspect element in your browser and then open `Source` tab. 
Press `ctrl + P` to search the file in which you want to put the debug points.
Put debug points by clicking on the `row number`. 
This way you need not to go to eclipse that often.

Comment: The second approach can be used if you're running GWT 2.6+ in SuperDev mode. You can only debug the Javascript side, and because of GWT's javascript minifying it can get a bit tiresome, but that may be enough to find out the service calls, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by searching the code for the listeners of whatever events you are interested in and go from there. I work in EXT JS and I do this all the time.

Following all code paths through is the only guarantee unless all calls to the backend go through some known class.

Monitoring the network is also a good way to go.

This can be done in Chrome through the "Developer Tools" on the Network tab.

Comment: i can put breakpoints to listeners and see what they are doing in the debugger. anything more specific than this? also - anything more specific to following all code paths?

Answer (score 0):

In GWT you have on the client side "import java.util.logging.Logger;" which output your debug info to the browsers console. On the server side you just use "System.out.println("debug");" for debugging which goes to the Apaches Tomcat log files. Which makes debugging on a live server a bit easier.

GWT uses RPC's for communication between the client and server. The data sent is serialized and can be a whole class if needed. The three folder for source in a module as 'client', 'server' and 'shared'.

For example a shared class used for sending data back and forth: (The blank constructor is required to serialise the class)

```
public class MySharedData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1987236748763652L; // used for serializing data

    public List<String> lotsOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); // use most java vars
    public int width, height;

    public MySharedData() {} // 'need' a blank constructor
    public MySharedData(MySharedData data) { //do stuff } // also can
}
```

On the server side it may look something like this:

```
public class MyServerRPCImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyServerRPC {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4435555929902374350L;

    public List<String> getStringList(int var, List<String> strs) {
        // do stuff
        System.out.println("debugging output"); // to tomcat log file
        return stringList;
    }
}
```

The client will use an Asynchronous callback with two methods, onSuccess() and onFailure() so you can handle call failures. To use this is something along the lines of:

```
public class MyGWTApp implements EntryPoint {
    // the server RPC class
    final MyServerRPCAsync server = GWT.create(MyServerRPC.class); // create RPC instance
    final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("tag");

    public void doSomething() {
        MySharedData data = new MySharedData();
        server.getStringList(data, new AsyncCallback<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                log.info("error"); // logging goes to the javascript console output
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<String> result) {
                log.info("call worked");
            }
        };)
    }
}
```

The above is my way of managing logging as my projects have to run straight from a Tomcat server. I also believe the server logging when run from Eclipse will go to Eclipse's console log, but I'm unsure on that. All server output and errors, including stack traces will be in the /var/log/tomcat/ folder on linux, or the equivalent on Windows. I can honestly say, I've yet not used breakpoints debugging with GWT.

Client and server code is in separate classes in their own folders within the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that sometimes debugger is used in situations where other tools can also help (not sure if this is the situation here - but bear with me just another two sentences):

(1) you can grep the relevant html asset , grep is a wonderful tool to learn large systems

(2) you can add log , in some cases you can switch to debug mode and see tons of log traces

Answer (score 0):

Use **Network** tab in developer tools of your preferred browser you are using to test.

**CHROME**

Press F12 or alternatively choose from menu - tools > developer tools
[image]

**FIREFOX**

Press F12 or alternatively choose from menu - Developer > toggle tools
[image]

**IE**

Press F12
[image]